# Finding a totally nasty, complex, Schröding-Bohr-Bug

Tags: c++, initialization

I have a really nasty bug in my program, which grew quite complex over time. It's probably the worst bug I've ever had.

I *think* that it might be related to a static variable initialization fiasco, **but how can I ensure myself of that?**

When the bug strikes, the program crashes due to heap corruption at a random point after startup, but far inside the main() function.

To be honest, I don't know what to do.

I'm on Windows 7 using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Comment: If you can't help yourself, then we can't help you for sure, since we don't have your code.

Comment: No code == "not a real question". Impossible to debug without it.

Comment: I suspect it has nothing to do with statics, and people that use the term "static initialisation fiasco" are normally talking out of their arse. Heap corruption is very common in badly-written C++ programs - you probably deleted something twice, or overwrote something.

Answer (score 1):

> my program, which grew quite complex
>   over time

Do you keep backups of previous versions?
Find an older version that worked and continue working based on that version...

There is a famous quote out there: 
"Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it." --Brian Kernighan

If this program has become more complicated than you can handle then it may be time to think about refactoring.

(This is in no way intended to be demeaning or to be taken as a personal attack...)

Answer (score 0):

Run your program in the debugger, and step through the code until you see what's wrong. Place breakpoints liberally anywhere you think the bug might be caused.

Answer (score -2):

Try debugging your program with gdb.

Comment: Does that debugger work on Windows as well?

Comment: Sort of, but VS2010 comes with an excellent (and *much* more user-friendly) debugger than GDB. Use it.

Comment: I'm using it already, but it doesn't bring me any further. The program runs perfectly to a certain point, and crashes randomly at a completely unrelated function in an unrelated third party library. The callstack doesn't help either

Comment: So step through earlier parts of the program. If you suspect the bug is related to static initialization, then step through the initialization of all your statics, and verify that they're in the correct state when they're used.

Comment: The OP didn't specify the OS. Not everyone is running windows.

Comment: @George "I'm on Windows 7 using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010"

Comment: Was that on the original post? Anyway forgive me if I had missed that.